# Cannot add rows to DataTable from another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, data-binding, datatable

Here is a code sample, you will need to place a `ListBox` called `list_of_items` onto the form, to reproduce the issue I'm having:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Form1
  Dim _dt As DataTable

  Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    _dt = New DataTable
    With _dt.Columns
      .Add("key")
      .Add("value")
    End With
    With list_of_items
      .ValueMember = "key"
      .DisplayMember = "value"
      .DataSource = _dt
    End With
    Dim addItemsTask As New Task(AddressOf AddThreeItems)
    addItemsTask.Start() 'does not add anything when done
    'AddThreeItems() #doing this instead works!
  End Sub

  Private Sub AddThreeItems()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    With _dt.Rows
      .Add({"1", "One"})
      .Add({"2", "Two"})
      .Add({"3", "Three"})
    End With
    Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Text = "Separate thread is done")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Problem is that rows do get added physically, so `DataTable.Rows.Count` increases, but visually nothing happens. I tried calling `Refresh`, resetting `DataSource` to `Nothing` and back - it does not help. If I switch this to single thread processing, rows get added just fine with the illustrated approach. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around `Me.Invoke` and found that if I add a dummy record synchronously using `Invoke`, all records I added previously actually get added. Then I just need to remove this dummy record from a `DataTable`. If you have a better solution or a more elegant workaround, or you can explain why it works like this, please feel free to post it as an answer. Here is how the code looks now:

```
Private Sub AddThreeItems()
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
  With _dt.Rows
    .Add({"1", "One"})
    .Add({"2", "Two"})
    .Add({"3", "Three"})
  End With
  Me.Invoke(Sub()
              _dt.Rows.Add()
              _dt.Rows.RemoveAt(_dt.Rows.Count - 1)
              Me.Text = "Separate thread is done"
            End Sub)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Reassign the data source

```
Me.Invoke(
    Sub()
        list_of_items.DataSource = Nothing 
        list_of_items.DataSource = _dt 
        Me.Text = "Separate thread is done"
    End Sub
)
```

Comment: It works, but it defeats the purpose - avoid re-assignment of `DataSource`. Suppose you have 100000 rows in there, and you just need to add one. I will modify your example to fix the issue with `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`, that get reset - you have to specify them again. Still, +1.